# Cannot interact with Android VM - VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to create a simple Android application to better learn about the Android platform. The first step was installing Android studio. Unfortunately, though, using Android Emulator was impossible, because my CPU has not VT-x support.

In order to overcome this, I chose the other path I had available: I installed an Android system on a virtual machine using VirtualBox. And here's where I met my last problem: After the installation, which went OK, I rebooted the system, and now I am stuck in a panel where I have to choose the language, because I cannot seem to be able to do anything using my mouse or keyboard. The first thing that came to mind, was  that I needed some kind of touch input, which I don't have on my laptop... Any advice to solve this in order to be able to use Android in the VM?

Comment: I ended up using Genymotion, so as to also get the Android Studio integration to work (by using just VirtualBox,the next issue would be getting the Android studio to recognize my virtual device). Very easy and fast solution, I recommend it.  I did not solve the exact problem as described above.

Comment: I've installed Android 4.4 in VirtualBox without any problems, and it runs just fine, albeit a little slow.  In the toolbar menu for the VirtualBox host there is a item called "Integrate Mouse" - which, well, enables the mouse!

Comment: Here are the directions I used to successfully install Android on VirtualBox: http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/

Answer (score 0):

[You might try Andyroid](http://www.andyroid.net/).  It is a virtual machine that hosts Android and the wrapper is specialized to accomodate for the idiosyncracies that arise from using a virtual hand-held device.  [I had issues with rotation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129132/prevent-screen-from-rotating-in-android-vm/129350#129350) using Android in VirtualBox and solved it like this.  Andyroid has a toggle switch that enables/disables the use of VT-x, so it is possible on a CPU without it.  One advantage Andyroid has over a regular VirtualBox solution is that it is tuned for Android.

Answer (score 0):

In order to interact with Android when you are lacking a touch screen, you need to enable Mouse integration AND perhaps tweak the keyboard settings to make sure that "Auto Capture Keyboard" is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with Android Virtual Box with "Tab" and "Enter" Keys.

Be careful, when you move the input focus with tab, watch the slight change in UI, and then press Enter.