# Enable interaction with screen when running Android-x86

Tags: android-x86, virtualization

I am running VMware Workstation Player 12 (henceforth as Player) on Windows 7. I successfully installed [android-4.4-r3](http://www.android-x86.org/download). However, I can't interact with the screen. Keyboard works fine (I used it for partitioning disk, install grub and some other things).

According to [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96184/cannot-interact-with-android-vm-virtualbox?), I should tweak input menu, but there is no longer an input menu in Player!

When I click on player, once screen saver is on, windows pointer disappear, and I could no longer have interaction with keyboard.

Am I missing the obvious?

Comment: That's rather an issue with your VMWare player than with Android (so I'm not sure if it fits here). As you already observed, we have no `vmware` tag, for good reasons (as your question seems to prove): VirtualBox is what's recommended for running Android in a VM.

Comment: I can create but I didn't bother to create a VMware product specific tag because I'm not clear whether this question would remain open. Anyhow, I think I may have ended up changing the intent a bit.  You originally wrote: "*I can't touch the screen*" which seems to suggest you've a touch enabled device. However, I changed the intent considering that you don't have a touch enabled device. Feel free to [edit] the question for required corrections.

Comment: This question looks totally on-topic to me, since it is about getting input to work for an Android install.  I use VMware as well so the answer would be interesting to me.

Comment: @Firelord your edition is fine, it cover my intend. Maybe virtual box is "official" emulator but I have seen vmware questions, and andydroid is able to use it fine. so I was wondering if someone could come with a solution. (comment edited to fix typos).